# Getting Error : Trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am a beginner in the CodeIgniter. Working on one small basic project, while I am working on the List view I get an error " Trying to get property of non-object.

Please help me! 
Here the screen shots.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrIbN.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J14Bu.png)

Here is my view :

```
<ul id="actions">
 <h4>List Actions</h4>
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>task/add/  <?php echo $list_detail->id; ?>"> Add Task</a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>lists/edit/ <?php echo $list_detail->id; ?>"> Edit List</a></li>
 <li><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="<?php echo base_url();?>lists/delete/<?php echo $list_detail->id;?>"> Delete List</a></li></ul>
 <h1><?php echo $list_detail->list_name; ?></h1>
 Created on : <strong><?php echo date("n-j-Y",strtotime($list_detail->create_date)); ?></strong>
 <br/><br/>
 <div style="max-width:500px;"><?php echo $list_detail->list_body; ?></div>
 <!-- <?php //echo print_r($query); ?>
 -->


 <br/><br/>
```

Here is Controller

```
 public function show($id){

    $data['list_detail'] = $this->List_model->get_lists($id);

    $data['main_content']='lists/show';
    $this->load->view('layout/main',$data);

 }
```

Here is model

```
public function get_list($id){

        $query=$this->db->get('lists');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Comment: Error itself is descriptive enough.

Comment: I think you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey I try to solve it by using row() ...but it giving me same error

Comment: @Nick I have added a answer hope it helps.

Comment: Have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This error is generating because you are trying to access an array in class object style.

Ex:

```
$data['list_details'] = 'some value';
```

and accessing it like:

```
$data->list_details;   // it will generate the error "Trying to get property of non object"
```

Answer (score 0):

When your using `$query->row()` on your model function then on controller

Model Function

```
public function get_list($id) {
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('lists');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Controller

```
public function show($id){
    // Gets data where it belongs with that id

    $list_data = $this->model_name->get_list($id);

    $data['id'] = $list_data->id;
    $data['create_date'] = $list_data->create_date;
    $data['list_body'] = $list_data->list_body; 

    $this->load->view('someview', $data);

}
```

When your using `$query->row_array();` on your model function then on controller

```
public function get_list($id) {
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('lists');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function show($id) {
    // Gets data where it belongs with that id

    $list_data = $this->model_name->get_list($id);

    $data['id'] = $list_data['id'];
    $data['create_date'] = $list_data['create_date'];
    $data['list_body'] = $list_data['list_body']; 

    $this->load->view('someview', $data);

}
```

On view then you can access

```
<?php echo $id;?>
<?php echo $create_date;?>
<?php echo $list_body;?>
```

## Update for multiple data

```
public function get_list() {
    $query = $this->db->get('lists');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
$results = $this->model_name->get_list();

// Or
//$results[] = $this->model_name->get_list();

$data['list_detail'] = $results;

$this->load->view('someview', $data);
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($list_detail as $list) {?>
   <?php echo $list->id;?>
   <?php echo $list->create_date;?>
   <?php echo $list->list_body;?>
<?php  }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After viewing your code. I think you have written wrong in your **model function**

**Your model function must be like below**

```
public function get_list($id) {
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('lists');
    return $query->row();
}
```

Also in your view before you print the value please check it with the condition of `!empty($list_details)`. so if value is not there still it will not throw any error.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey , Getting same error after trying your suggestion.

Comment: try to `print_r($data);die;` in your controller function before you load the view and check are you getting the proper data or not.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller you are calling the model function as get_lists().

But there is no function as get_lists in model. U need to change the function name in controller to get_list()

Comment: Hey, Thanks! Brother I just miss that one :)